# JApplet can't view properly in Safari browser. Mainly button, label and combo-box

Tags: java, swing, applet, japplet

I made an applet using Swing. This is working fine in all Windows browsers. But when we run same applet on Mac. machine in Safari browser, it shows problems with labels, buttons and combo boxes. What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Can we run swing on browser? I thought only applet is supported.

Comment: @ramesh *"What should I do to fix this?"*  Fix the code.  Ensure the GUI is constructed and altered on the EDT, and `validate()` is called afterwards.  If that fails to fix the problem, prepare an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html) & post it to the thread.  @Harry See [JApplet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JApplet.html) as well as the example code shown in the [info. on the applet tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/applet/info).  BTW - to ramesh - the code shown at the last link is constructed on the EDT (though I did not `validate()`) - does it work in Safari?

Comment: This is often due to using absolute positioning and/or having fixed size components.

Answer (score 0):

Emm... if the look and feel is set to "UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName()" the Mac is totally changes the usual look and feel and, of course, (in absolute components location) all components shapes and sizes get wrong... so the thing I can suggest in your case is...

> This is working fine in all Windows browsers.

so set look and feel manually to the IE (Windows) one as

```
"com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel"
```

code integration examples you can find here [look and feel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html)

Good luck